# Can an sh (or index file) be used in CCC profiles instead of the binary?

Tags: scripts, catalyst, binary

I am trying to set custom graphical options in AMD Catalyst Control Center for a specific program. There is a single sh file that launches it but there are 4 completely different binaries (not counting 32-bit) on which the program runs. If I specify the shell script for Catalyst to apply 3D settings on, will they pass to the binaries? Or will I have to make individual profiles to every single binary involved in the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I spent hours doing benchmarks and one of the things I discovered is that the graphical options have to apply directly to the binary, not the shell-script.